# Is the integral $\int_0^T |f(x)| dx$ always strictly greater than $0$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, complex-analysis, examples-counterexamples

Let $T>0$ be fixed and let $f$ be a real valued integrable function such that $f\not\equiv 0$.

Is it always true that
$$\int_0^T |f(x)| \ dx >0 \space ?$$

If yes, could someone give an hint for the proof? If not, could you please exhibit a counterexample?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: $f=1_{\{0\}}$. ${}{}$

Comment: @copper.hat what does your notation mean?

Comment: Or any other function $f$ that is equal to zero almost everywhere

Comment: It is the indicator function of the set $\{0\}$, that is, $f(0) = 1$ and $f(x) = 0$ for $x \neq 0$.

Comment: If $f$ was continuous, then the statement would hold.

Comment: The integral is strictly positive if and only if $f$ is not zero almost everywhere.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your useful comments.

Comment: By Riemann-Lebesgue Theorem, the set of discontinuities must be measure 0. Hence, the function must be identically zero everywhere else.

Comment: $f$ not identically zero isn't really a big thing I think. You can always do the next best thing: Make it identically zero except for 1 point. Finitely many points I believe works. Even countably many points I think will work, but maybe popcorn function or something will disprove me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It suffices to take a function $f$ that is $0$ almost everywhere and non-zero at a countably finite number of points.

For example, consider the function $f(x) = \mathbb{1}_{\{x=3\}} $ and note that:

$$\int_0^5|  f(x) |\ dx = 0$$

as $x=0$ almost everywhere in this interval and we can quite easily show using the basic properties of the Lebesgue measure that an integral of this form will be equal to $0$ since the Lebesgue measure of any countable set of real numbers is equal to $0$ by construction.

Answer (score 1):

It’s worth pointing out that the statement is almost true — if $f \ne 0$ on a set of positive measure, then the statement holds on the entire real line (or any set containing a positively measured subset of the set-theoretic support. Note the slight distinguishment between a set-theoretic and a topological support. Here we refer to the prior):

Suppose
$$
0 <
\mu \left ( \text{supp} f \right )=
\mu \left \{f \ne 0 \right \} =
\mu \left (\bigcup_{n = 1}^\infty \left \{|f| > \frac 1 n \right \} \right )
$$

(convince yourself of the set equality $\left \{f \ne 0 \right \} = \bigcup_{n = 1}^\infty \left \{|f| > \frac 1 n \right \}$).

Then, I claim there exists $n_0 \in \Bbb N$ for which $\mu \left \{|f| > \frac 1 {n_0} \right \} > 0$, for otherwise $\mu \left \{|f| > \frac 1 n \right \} = 0$ for all $n \ge 1$, and we arrive at the following contradiction:

$$
0 <
\mu \left ( \text{supp} f \right )=
\mu \left \{f \ne 0 \right \} =
\mu \left (\bigcup_{n = 1}^\infty \left \{|f| > \frac 1 n \right \} \right ) \le
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \mu \left \{|f| > \frac 1 n \right \} =
\sum_{n=1}^\infty 0 =
0
$$

Finally,

$$
\int_{\Bbb R} |f| \ge
\int_{|f| > \frac 1 {n_0}} |f| \ge
\frac 1 {n_0} \cdot \mu \left \{|f| > \frac 1 {n_0} \right \} >
0
$$